# How to preview facebook status update with FB SDK 3.1 and iOS<6?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook-ios-sdk

I implemented fb status update in my iphone app using FBRequestConnection. 
I want to show the user what will be posted on their wall. As i can see it, it can only be done in iOS6 with the help of FBNativeDialogs.

How to do it for iOS5?

Is it a good practice to post it after alertdialog in iOS5 (no preview of post) and with FBNativeDialogs in iOS6?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow this guide with the new Facebook SDK:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-games/feed/

Shows how to do it in iOS6 and iOS 5.